# Updating a sonar quality profile programmatically

Tags: java, sonarqube, checkstyle

I created a sonar plugin, which extends the sonar checkstyle plugin by adding more custom made checkstyle checks. The plugin also creates a new quality profile with all my rules, when I restart the sonar server. So far this works all fine.

My Question is now: How can I update the profile, when I add new developed checks?

I tried to delete the profile manually as an administrator on the server in order to create a "new" profile on startup. But the deleted profile remains somewhere and no new profile is added.

Here is the code, which is responsible for creating the profile:

```
public RulesProfile createProfile(ValidationMessages inValidation) {

return xmlParser.parseResource(getClass().getClassLoader(), "profile.xml" ,inValidation);
}
```